# Haskell SDL console window

Tags: haskell, sdl

I'm using Haskell's bindings for SDL in Windows. So, basically, I know that standard output in SDL by default streamed to some txt files and you need to  [issue some commands](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_Console) to get additional console window output along with standard SDL window.

As far as Haskell's bindings are concearned, is there a similar way to add console window? I had no luck of finding this function in [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL-0.6.5/docs/doc-index-All.html).

Comment: A quick google search doesn't turn up anything that provides freopen, but you can quite easily do it yourself: create a c file with `void sdl_redirect(void) { ... }`, then put `foreign import ccall unsafe "sdl_redirect.c sdl_redirect" sdl_redirect :: IO ()` in your .hs file. You will need to enable `ForeignFunctionInterface`.

Comment: That was good idea. Strictly speaking, I've added #include <stdio.h> in C source and compiled with "ghc hs_source.hs sdl_redirect.c". But still same result - only graphical window appears.

Comment: Well, the link you gave does say that those solutions might not always work. Try to do the same in a very simple C program using SDL. If it doesn't work, your problem is not Haskell - get the C version working and the Haskell version will almost certainly work. If the C version does work, then something strange is being done by the Haskell bindings. In either case, I'm afraid I don't know much about the topic and can't help more.

Comment: Yes, I remember now - stuff was not working for me even on C code - I had to recompile SDL to get console output. Anyhow, thank you for advice - I've got closer to understanding the environment.